How do I label this table so it appears as "table 1: xyz"?
How to label this table, so it appears as [Table 1: xyz] and not [Table: xyz]? Currently using booktabs for making tables (and the tables are in beamer).
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\caption{xyz}
\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
Experiment Q & W \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I've taken the liberty of editing your code to make it minimally compilable. Feel free to revert.

You can use the numbered caption template:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\caption{xyz}
\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
Experiment Q & W \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


